# How to place the selected Li in h4 using jquery

Tags: jquery

[complete code JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/soul/EamPb/)

as shown in the code the selected state comes below the h4 , how to display the selected state in h4 and after selecting a state it just shows that particular state and not able to select other states

Comment: with valid HTML and only needed data  paste in fiddle

Comment: i have done it in fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made just simpler, you can decorate watever you want

```
$('h4').live('click',function() {
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast');    
});

$(".videostateId li").live('click',function(){
    if($(this).val() !==0) {
          if($('h4').html() =='State'){ 
              $('h4').text($(this).text()); }
          else {
            $('h4').append(","+$(this).text())
         }
          $('div.state_wrap').slideUp('fast'); 
    }        
});​
```

see [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/EamPb/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope its what you wanted to achieve

```
$(".videostateId li").click(function(){
          $('.address').html($(this).text()); //display selected text in h4
            $('.address').unbind('click'); //disable the click event
          $(this).siblings().hide();
      });
```